# Allow the user to stay signed in forever - Different implementation methods

Tags: session, cookies

I am developing an application and I'd like to offer the user a possibility to stay signed in *forever*. If he checks a box, his session should never end, unless he manually logs out or deletes the cookie. If he doesn't, his session cookie will expire on closing the browser.

I considered three ways to realise this, but all of them contain pros and cons:

- **Saving a cookie with the user name and his hashed password**:

  - Pro: The user can have multiple active sessions on different devices.
  - Con: If the cookie gets leaked by third parties, they can regenerate his session at any time unless he changes his password.
- **Generating a *token* which will be stored in the database and in the user's cookies. Then compare them**:

  - Pro: As soon as the user logs out, the token will be randomized and *all* of his sessions will be destroyed. He will definitely be logged of.
  - Con: The user can only log in forever with one device. As soon as he logs in from another device, accepting to be logged in forever, his other token will be overwritten.
- **Only hypothetically**: Save sessions forever on the server and give non-expiring cookies to the user.

  - Con: This is probably not realistic, because you can't store that much data in an efficient way.

I currently prefer the second way, because it does not seem to be as insecure as the first one and it's easily implementable. But I am still not convinced of it and I have seen that there are proven frameworks which do it another way.

Could you imagine another way which is maybe even better? What's your favorite and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never save the password in a cookie. The second method is fine, and is how I think you'll find most apps implement this feature. Note that the session storage doesn't need to be a database. The cookie contains some unique (unguessable!) id, and this id points to some unique storage. It could be a text file in a directory somewhere, a database row, a JSON string in memcached, whatever.

> Pro: As soon as the user logs out, the token will be randomized and
>   all of his sessions will be destroyed. He will definitely be logged
>   of.
>
> Con: The user can only log in forever with one device. As soon as
>   he logs in from another device, accepting to be logged in forever,
>   his other token will be overwritten.

Don't store the token id as a column in the user table. Instead create a new cross table that allows more than one session per user. So, each device will have its own separate token, and thus, its own separate session which can be managed individually.

When a user logs out, you destroy only that one cookie and its associated session store. Any other sessions that the user has outstanding will remain untouched.

Comment: Creating multiple tokens per user seems to be a very good idea! Thank you! This solves the problem of inadvertently overwriting the "unique token". I turned this over in my mind and I came across the following problem: If there are users who always sign in *forever* but delete all their cookies without logging of, they would kind of spam the database. Is there a better way to prevent this instead of deleting old sessions as soon as there are more than X ones? By the way - my first proposal did not intend to save the user's password in a cookie: I would save a hashed and salted representation.

Comment: I'd touch a timestamp on the session store whenever it's accessed, and then write a cron script (or build it into your app as garbage collection) that deletes all sessions that have not been accessed in X days. So it's only indefinite login if you stay active.

Comment: And yes, I understood about the hashing. It doesn't matter if it's hashed. If your app allows access based on an already-hashed password, then giving out the hashed password is no different than giving out the plaintext password.

Comment: Ah, now I get your point. Agreed, that's right. I just came across that because I *think* http://www.simplemachines.org does it that way IIRC. The timestamp based solution seems practical, but it could confuse the user, because if it says forever, he expects it to be forever. On the contrary everybody deletes his cookies every once in a while without thinking about it, so I concede that it is still the best solution. :-) Thank you very much for all your valuable suggestions!

Comment: Heh well unless you're willing to allow your session store to infinitely grow, then you don't really have a choice. :)

Comment: Good analysis, but there is a point about this discussion I don't understand well! How storing a not-guessable token in cookie is way better than storing the username and password pair?! I mean, in both cases, you suggest a stored **thing** which is enough to grant you to be encountered as logged-in user! For example by hijacking the stored token, one can easily change the password!

Comment: The token changes with each login, and is only valid for the length of the session -- so a hacker would have to sniff the token and hijack the session while the user is logged in. Possession of the token after the original user has logged out is useless. On the other hand, the user/pass doesn't change from login to login. So a hacker who sniffs it will be able to login from anywhere, at any later date, regardless of the original user's actions.